# How to know which display number for the variable DISPLAY will be exported when using ssh?

Tags: linux, ssh, display, gui

When I `ssh` to a server using `-X`, I am always confused about which display number I should export. It seems to me sometimes the display number has been used by something, so what I can do is only go through:

```
export DISPLAY=localhost:0 && xclock  
export DISPLAY=localhost:1 && xclock  
export DISPLAY=localhost:2 && xclock  
export DISPLAY=localhost:...
```

until the clock appears. I will then use that display number. Each time I log into the server, the display number which is able to tunnel the GUI data correctly would be different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sshd automatically sets `$DISPLAY` on the server side when X forwarding is enabled; there should be no reason for you to override its value.

Comment: Thanks! I will have to wait till next week when i can access the server and reply you back!